# dropdown is not staying when I hover over it

Tags: html, css

Whenever I hover over the dropdown I shows up but once I hover over the dropdown content it goes away I have no idea why this is happening because I have 2 dropdowns on my website and the first one works perfectly but when I copy and paste the code it fails anyways here is the code

```css
.about {
  position: absolute;
  right: 101px;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 32px;
  height: 68px;
}

.about:hover {
  background-color: #e2e0d7;
  transition: 1s;
}

.about-text:hover {
  opacity: 50%;
  transition: .5s
}

.about-dropdown {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #494642;
  padding-top: 36px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 36px;
  right: 101px;
  display: none;
}

.about:hover+.about-dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <p class="about-text">About-Page</p>
</div>
<div class="about-dropdown">
  <a class="about-me-text" href="About/About-Me">About-Me</a>
  <a class="about-credits-text" href="About/Credits">Credits</a>
  <a class="about-contact-me-text" href="About/Contact-Me">Contact-Me</a>
</div>
```

I tried this short line of code

```
.about:hover + .about-dropdown {display: block;}
```

I also removed the + sign but its still the same I also have another dropdown with this code and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you need to put about-dropdown div in about div right after p element and make a minor css change last line
here is the potential solution:
```

```css
.about {
    position: absolute;
    right: 101px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 32px;
    height: 68px;
}
.about:hover {
    background-color: #e2e0d7;
    transition: 1s;
}
.about-text:hover {
    opacity: 50%;
    transition: .5s
}
.about-dropdown {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: #494642;
    padding-top: 36px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 36px;
    right: 0px;
    display: none;
}
.about:hover  .about-dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
            <p class="about-text">
                About-Page
            </p>
  <div class="about-dropdown">
            <a class="about-me-text" href="About/About-Me">
                About-Me
            </a>
            <a class="about-credits-text" href="About/Credits">
                Credits
            </a>
            <a class="about-contact-me-text" href="About/Contact-Me">
                Contact-Me
            </a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

[solution](https://codepen.io/ugurozoz/pen/jOePEyw)

Comment: Please add your code directly to the answer, as an answer must be self-contained.